# Clips logic probem

Tags: logic, clips

I started learning clips in AI course but im havind trouble with clips logic functions

1.father of every man is his direct ancestor

math solution:

F(x,y) - x is father of y

DA(x,y) - x is direct ancestor of y

for every x,y : F(x,y) =>DA(x,y)

clips solution:

(defrule father_direct_ancestor

(father ?x ?y)

=>

(assert(direct_ancestor ?x ?y)
)

)

2.if someone is ancestor of someones direct ancestor, then he is ancestor of that person as well

math solution:

A(x,y) - x is ancestor of y

DA(x,y) - x is direct ancestor of y

for every x,y,z A(x,y)*DA(y,z) => A(x,z)

And here i cant figure out how to do it in clips.

Tried like this:

(defrule A

(D_A ?y ?z)

(A ?x ?y)

=>

(assert (A ?x ?z))
)

Comment: Your rule is fine. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: im having problem with grasping this language. It gives almost no feedback and when you make any sort of error it says everything is wrong.

Comment: The problem with your question is that there's no actual question because what you've included is correct.